# Kafka broker meet fatal issue, error log like "Connection to X was disconnected before the response was read"

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

All the brokers in cluster can start and work just fine, but sometimes one of the broker will meet problem. At that time, there are some cases:

- whole cluster is hang, nor producer and consumer are not work, hence the network flow is down to zero from monitor;
- use kafka-topic.sh describe the topic message, every replica is just fine, even the exceptional brokerid, and information in zk also normal;
- the file-description number increase gradually on abnormal broker, which is read from /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
- netstat the broker listen port 9092 display lots of "CLOSE_WAIT" status

Following is the error log shows from others brokers, while the abnormal broker log can not see any exception.

```
[2019-04-15 18:10:25,243] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=0, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=289971597, epoch=1254343) t
o node 1: java.io.IOException: Connection to 1 was disconnected before the response was read. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-04-15 18:10:25,244] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=0, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Error in response for fetch request (type=FetchRequest, replicaId=
0, maxWait=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=10485760, fetchData={atm_error_intf-7=(offset=538244, logStartOffset=5319, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Op
tional[13])}, isolationLevel=READ_UNCOMMITTED, toForget=, metadata=(sessionId=289971597, epoch=1254343)) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 1 was disconnected before the response was read
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:97)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:97)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchFromLeader(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:190)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:241)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:130)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3$adapted(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:129)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:129)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:111)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82)
[2019-04-15 18:10:57,275] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=0, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Error in response for fetch request (type=FetchRequest, replicaId=
0, maxWait=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=10485760, fetchData={ieg_qsm_guildstatechangereport4pandora-19=(offset=52347859, logStartOffset=38458463, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[50]), ieg_qsm_playerreporthighfrequency4pandora-10=(offset=97212897, logStartOffset=65418413, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[46]), ieg_qsmtest_guildstatechangereport4pandora-13=(offset=25771, logStartOffset=20917, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[46]), __consumer_offsets-10=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[57]), ieg_qsmtest_playerreporthighfrequency4pandora-7=(offset=141317, logStartOffset=118323, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[45]), __consumer_offsets-25=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[44]), ieg_qsmtest_playerlogin-15=(offset=59440, logStartOffset=52149, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[55]), dm_pdl_wefeng_findfriend_topic-12=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[42]), dm_pdl_wefeng_findfriend_topic_test-0=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[47]), ieg_qsmtest_guildstatechangereport4pandora-18=(offset=21042, logStartOffset=16441, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[56]), ieg_qsm_playerlogin-1=(offset=27414596, logStartOffset=17328842, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[45]), atm_error_intf-7=(offset=538244, logStartOffset=5319, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[13]), __consumer_offsets-30=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[51]), ieg_qsm_playerreporthighfrequency4pandora-15=(offset=87995984, logStartOffset=53470647, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[55]), __consumer_offsets-45=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[47]), ieg_qsm_playerlogin-6=(offset=25070198, logStartOffset=16224757, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[54]), ieg_qsmtest_playerreporthighfrequency4pandora-12=(offset=141878, logStartOffset=122257, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[56]), dm_pdl_wefeng_findfriend_topic-17=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[56]), ieg_qsm_guildstatechangereport4pandora-14=(offset=45869398, logStartOffset=27847747, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[47]), dm_pdl_wefeng_findfriend_topic_test-5=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[57]), atm_error_intf-27=(offset=539432, logStartOffset=5392, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[13]), ieg_qsmtest_playerlogin-10=(offset=66712, logStartOffset=55774, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[48]), __consumer_offsets-5=(offset=0, logStartOffset=0, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[47])}, isolationLevel=READ_UNCOMMITTED, toForget=, metadata=(sessionId=289971597, epoch=INITIAL)) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 1 was disconnected before the response was read
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:97)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:97)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchFromLeader(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:190)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:241)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:130)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3$adapted(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:129)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:129)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:111)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82)
```

-Xmx8G -Xms8G, this is the jvm heap size. I only can kill -9 the instance and restart to resume it.

- version kafka_2.12-2.1.0
- java
- CentOS 7

Comment: Hey Carl, Have you got any solution to this problem?  Please share if any! thanks,

Comment: @Avis It's a version bug of 2.1.0. You should update to 2.2.0 to fix it. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7802